# Relaying UART1 with UART2 within an ISR() (PIC24H)

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am programming a microcontroller of the PIC24H family and using xc16 compiler.

I am relaying U1RX-data to U2TX within `main()`, but when I try that in an ISR it does not work.

I am sending commands to the U1RX and the ISR() is down below. At U2RX, there are databytes coming in constantly and I want to relay 500 of them with the U1TX. The results of this is that U1TX is relaying the first 4 databytes from U2RX but then re-sending the 4th byte over and over again.

When I copy the `for` loop below into my `main()` it all works properly. In the ISR(), its like that U2RX's corresponding FIFObuffer is not clearing when read so the buffer overflows and stops reading further incoming data to U2RX. I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to approach the problem here. The variables `tmp` and `command` are globally declared.

```
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, auto_psv, shadow)) _U1RXInterrupt(void)
{
    command = U1RXREG;
    if(command=='d'){
        for(i=0;i<500;i++){
            while(U2STAbits.URXDA==0);
            tmp=U2RXREG;
            while(U1STAbits.UTXBF==1); //
            U1TXREG=tmp;
           }
    }
}
```

Edit: I added the first line in the ISR().

Comment: You can't just copy your loop from `main()` into an ISR and expect it to work. You even copied the command from the main loop. The ISR would be triggered on receipt of every RX data char, you would clear the interrupt status and transmit the char, and return from the interrupt. But sitting there in a loop is not what you do in an ISR.

Comment: generally you don't want a loop of 500 things with io in an ISR... try setting a flag to tell main to do it... or something similar... you could be re-firing your ISR from inside of your ISR, or it maybe isn't getting finished before the timer fires it or something... (I don't know what your program is doing.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I realize now how stupied my code looks like. I should have presented it as an psuedocode due to the missing of some details that should've been there. I did not copy the command from main(), i corrected it with adding command = U1RXREG;  a few mins after I posted. I will disable all interrupts when entering the ISR() to make sure that nothing is interrupting it and enabling interrupts before leaving the ISR(). And I will place the loop in a function wich is going to be called by the ISR(). My program is getting GPS-data with U2RX and relaying it to an RF-transmitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to draw an answer from the various comments.

If the `main()` has nothing else to do, and there are no other interrupts, you might be able to "get away with" patching all 500 chars from one UART to another under interrupt, once the first interrupt has ocurred, and perhaps it would be a useful exercise to get that working.

But that's not how you should use an interrupt. If you have other tasks in `main()`, and equal or lower priority interrupts, the relatively huge time that this interrupt will take (500 chars at 9600 baud = half a second) will make the processor what is known as "interrupt-bound", that is, the other processes are frozen out.

As your project gains complexity, you won't want to restrict `main()` to this task, and there is no need to for it be involved at all, after setting up the UARTs and IRQs. After that it can calculate `π` ad infinitum if you want.

I am a bit perplexed as to your sequence of operations. A command `'d'` is received from U1 which tells you to patch 500 chars from U2 to U1.

I suggest one way to tackle this (and there are many) seeing as you really want to use interrupts, is to wait until the command is received from U1 - in `main()`. You then configure, and enable, interrupts for RXD on U2.

Then the job of the ISR will be to receive data from U2 and transmit it thru U1. If both UARTS have the same clock and the same baud rate, there should not be a synchronisation problem, since a UART is typically buffered internally: once it begins to transmit, the TXD register is available to hold another character, so any stagnation in the ISR should be minimal.

I can't write the actual code for you, since it would be supposed to work, but here is some *very* pseudo code, and I don't have a PIC handy (or wish to research its operational details).

```
ISR
    has been invoked because U2 has a char RXD
    you *might* need to check RXD status as a required sequence to clear the interrupt
    read the RXD register, which also might clear the interrupt status
    if not, specifically clear the interrupt status
    while (U1 TXD busy);
    write char to U1
    if (chars received == 500)
        disable U2 RXD interrupt
    return from interrupt
```

Answer (score 1):

ISR's *must* be kept lean and mean and the code made hyper-efficient if there is any hope of keeping up with the buffer on a UART.  Experiment with the BAUD rate just to find the point at which your code can keep up, to help discover the right heuristic and see how far away you are from achieving your goal.

Success could depend on how fast your micro controller is, as well, and how many tasks it is running. If the microcontroller has a built in UART theoretically you should be able to manage keeping the FIFO from overflowing.  On the other hand, if you paired up a UART with an insufficiently-powered micro controller, you might not be able to optimize your way out of the problem.

Besides the suggestion to offload the lower-priority work to the main thread and keep the ISR fast (that someone made in the comments), you will want to carefully look at the timing of all of the lines of code and try every trick in the book to get them to run faster. One expensive instruction can ruin your whole day, so get *real* creative in finding ways to save time.

EDIT: Another thing to consider - look at the assembly language your C compiler creates.  A good compiler should let you inline assembly language instructions to allow you to hyper-optimize for your particular case. Generally in an ISR it would just be a small number of instructions that you have to find and implement.

EDIT 2: A PIC 24 series should be fast enough if you code it right and select a fast oscillator or crystal and run the chip at a good clock rate.  Also consider the divisor the UART might be using to achieve its rate vs. the PIC clock rate.  It is conceivable (to me) that an even division that could be accomplished internally via shifting would be better than one where math was required.

Comment: @Pax -note I added two edits to the answer since you first may have seen it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and comments, 1s and 0s. As soon as I continue with the project I will experiment and try solve the problem. When its done I will report the solution and give creds to the users that earns it.

Comment: @Pax re your above comment: *"I will disable all interrupts when entering the ISR() to make sure that nothing is interrupting it and enabling interrupts before leaving the ISR()."* Firstly, it's a bad route to start your career in ISR handling, and contrary to the spirit of "mean and lean" as answered. Secondly, interrupts are disabled by default when you enter an ISR, so if yours is low priority you can re-enable interrupts so that higher priority interrupts can still function (or even allow your own ISR to be re-entrant!), although I add, this is *not* a beginner's technique.

Comment: @1sand0s I was only trying to discourage OP from this particular technique of hogging an interrupt. He should experiment every which way he can, since if it breaks, you only have to turn it off and try again.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry I am not sure if I can agree with that "interrupts are disabled by default when you enter an ISR so if yours is low priority you can re-enable interrupts..." According to PIC24H family reference manual: "Interrupts are nestable by default. Any ISR in progress can be interrupted by another source of interrupt with a higher user-assigned priority level".  I interpret it like theres no need to "re-enable" higher prio interrupts  to interrupt lower prio ones. The CPU copies the priority level of the interrupt and restores the priority from the stack when ISR is finished.

Comment: @Pax you got me - well done, my PIC is rusty, but it's still not good technique to linger in an interrupt.

Comment: @Pax I think what he meant is that equal and lower-priority interrupts are implicitly blocked when an interrupt is being serviced.  Higher ones can interrupt. That's the point of the hierarchy.  So he wonders what the point of disabling any interrupts in the ISR is in your situation if the implicit functioning of the interrupt hierarchy should cover your bases. Some interrupts on some processors can't be disabled. Those are called NMIs (Non-maskable Interrupts).

Comment: @Pax in particular your ISR waits on status with every lower or equal priority task blocked.

Comment: @WeatherVane So do you prefer that the ISR, instead, is activating a task in main() that do "all the work" instead?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use an interrupt it should somehow pass *one* input char to `main()`, which will process it. `main()` should sit there waiting for it, and/or doing other tasks.

Comment: @Pax the simplest way to  do that is to use two vars. One for data, one for status. The interrupt would write to the data and set the status. Main would see the status, collect the value, and clear the status. This is a basic way of doing things, it's a one-char buffer. In effect, it's a more generalised way of handling the UART itself. Now you have a driver!

Comment: @WeatherVane, put it in an answer so others can see it.

Comment: You guys are the best:) Next time I continue with the project, I will definatly approach the problem as you suggest! I will report when its done!

Comment: @WeatherVane For me, your driver-example means constant polling. I was hoping that my "superloop" would be empty to only listen to interrupts. But I will definatly start with your idea and work my way towards more interrupt-driven loop to that point the program is still solid. Anyway, but big thanks to both of you weather and 10101010.

Comment: Hey @Pax thanks. I got caught up hoping you'd vindicate my answers and started losing patience. Thanks for clearing up that it is worth the effort and doing you some good and you appreciate the effort and actually learning this technique.  You'd be surprised at how some new users at this site are. all taking a no giving. some expect you to teach them CS and do their homework for them from scatch

Comment: @WeatherVane your answer wins because it is beyond generalities and moves toward a specific solution and strategy. Brady actually pinpointed what was wrong in the initial scenario Succinctly first